# How to terminate adb.exe on windows? What keeps restarting it?

Tags: android, windows, adb

I am trying to terminate adb.exe on my Windows machine. I am using `taskkill /F /IM adb.exe /T` to do this. However each time I do it, 3 adb.exe instances come back into the task manager process view. Something is restarting them.

I'm trying to do some connection-between-virtual-machine stuff and I need adb.exe to die and stay dead on the Windows host, because it is interfering.

How do I identify what is restarting these processes? Or otherwise make adb.exe stay dead without doing extreme stuff like temporarily deleting it from the Windows host?

Extra notes:
When I run the taskkill, a process group called "Service Host: DCOM Server Process Launcher" jumps to the top of the process list at 20% cpu, so maybe it's what is responsible.

No, adb kill-server etc is no more effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help you if you look at process explorer. It resolves process trees and may lead you to the starting process.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

However, if I start the adb server through a command promt, it shows adb.exe as subprocess of cmd.exe only for some seconds and then gets handed up as independend process. You might want to have the process explorer open and monitor the restarting procedure of adb.exe.

Comment: yes this is perfect, it shows that genymotion is restarting it itself on the windows side, not sure how to tell it to stop that though (I want to connect to  the android VM inside using tcpip)

Comment: the process explorer showed that adb was being kicked off my the sync manager of an Android phone I had about 4 phones ago - an HTC.  Wow.

Answer (score 1):

To kill adb you can use `adb kill-server` and start it with `adb start-server`
adb.exe is `platform-tools` folder in your Android SDK.

Also you can get it from chocolatey packages https://chocolatey.org/packages/adb

Comment: Are you a literal android?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users:

> Simply Open TaskManager --> Processes --> Background processes --> Select ADB --> End Task.

It will stop ADB from running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it was a gradle daemon who was keep restarting an adb server. To prevent him doing so, I used `gradle --stop`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar issue:

When using flutter, check if you have two `adb.exe` executables.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `cmd`
2. Type `cd..` to exit current directory
3. Comes to the main directory i.e.C:> directory
4. Now type **adb kill-server** and press enter
5. Now go to the `adb` directory means the path where `adb` is located ex.-> `[your path]\AndroidStudioProjects\sdk\sdk\platform-tools`
6. Delete the `adb.exe`
7. Download latest platform-tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)
8. Unzip it
9. copy the complete folder and paste inside `[your path]\AndroidStudioProjects\sdk\sdk\platform-tools`

Answer (score 0):

My Android Studio has an adb file inside /home/myuser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/ with the version 1.0.41.

*Note where I put myuser could be your name, whatever, just locate your Android path.*

My error was:
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39)

When you type just `adb` in terminal, this command will be related with the adb archive inside /usr/bin.

So, I did these steps inside terminal:

1. `adb version`

> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39

2. `cd /usr/bin`
3. `sudo rm adb`
4. `cd /home/**myuser**/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/`
5. Please check if there is an adb file inside your path
   Now copy to /usr/bin
6. `sudo cp adb /usr/bin`
7. `adb version` again

> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41

With this done, both of them have the same adb file.

If in the future the SDK Manager asks to upgrade platform-tools and the error appears again, remember to perform these steps again.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use software such as Process lesso for example, or an event viewer to see who is starting adb and then switch it off.

It is advisable to check the path of the adb that is running and check that the files are OK.

Re-download the adb tool from offical website.

https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools#downloads

Also, scan your computer for viruses!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35369311)